# Speed up a Laravel query where a field from relationship matches at least all elements of a given array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using the query below to get all results matching at least all elements of an array:

```
$colors_array = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

Foo::with('colors')
  ->whereHas(
    'colors',
    function ($query) use ($colors_array) {
      $query->distinct()->whereIn('name', $colors_array);
    },
    '=',
    count($colors_array)
  );
```

But this query is very slow, is there a better syntax to speed it up ?

Comment: Did you tried to set an index on `colors.name` in your database? this might speed things up significantly

Comment: Indeed, it's much faster! Thanks a lot!